# Weird typechecker behavior when using apply on a list of sets in typed racket

Tags: types, racket, typed-racket

I have a list of sets and I want to take a union of those.

Something like the following

```
(apply set-union (list (set 'a) (set 'b)))
```

Which works and gives me the correct result (set 'a 'b)

Now if I try to write the same code like this:

```
(: l (Listof (Setof Symbol)))
(define l (list (set 'a) (set 'b)))
(apply set-union l)
```

Then I get the following error:

```
Type Checker: Bad arguments to function in `apply':
  Domains: (Listof e)(Listof e) *
           (Setof e)(Setof e) *
  Arguments: (Listof (Setof Symbol))
```

How can I apply the set-union function to a list of sets?

I should mention that the same piece of code works with untyped racket language or with using language [typed/racket/no-check](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/Typed_Racket_Syntax_Without_Type_Checking.html), which is why I believe that it's definitely a typechecking issue.

Answer (score 2):

The error message notes that the domain of the function involving sets is `(Setof e) (Setof e) *`, which means `set-union` needs *at least one* argument to be correctly applied. `(Listof (Setof Symbol))` could be the empty list, which would cause a runtime error.

Therefore, you should give `l` a more specific type. You could use `(List (Setof Symbol) (Setof Symbol))` to describe it most precisely, or if you just want a type that captures the notion of “a list of sets with at least one element,” you can use the type `(Pairof (Setof Symbol) (Listof (Setof Symbol)))`.

Answer (score 1):

@Alexis King's diagnosis is correct, and her suggestion of using a more specific type for the input list is a good one if you know the list is non-empty. However in some cases it's not possible to change the type of the input list: sometimes the list is empty and you have to deal with it.

When the list is empty, you want an empty set, so you can apply `set-union` to the empty set in addition to the list:

```
(define l (list))
(apply set-union (set) l)
;=> (set)
```

This gets Typed Racket to accept the union even when `l` has the original type `(Listof (Setof Symbol))` which can be empty:

```
(: l (Listof (Setof Symbol)))
(define l (list (set 'a) (set 'b)))
(apply set-union (set) l)
;=> (set 'a 'b)
```

To make sure the result type can be specific, so that the union can be `(Setof Symbol)`, you should make sure `(set)` has a type at least as specific. In this case the empty set can have type `(Setof Nothing)`, so you can use `((inst set Nothing))`.

```
(: l (Listof (Setof Symbol)))
(define l (list (set 'a) (set 'b)))
(apply set-union ((inst set Nothing)) l)
;- : (Setof Symbol)
;=> (set 'a 'b)
```

Comment: If you want the result to be of a useful type, e.g. `(: result (Setof Symbol))` then you have to type-cast the (set), e.g. `(define result (apply set-union (cast (set) (Setof Symbol)) l))`. Otherwise it defaults to `(Setof Any)`

Comment: Oh, thanks for catching that. Although you shouldn't use `cast` here since that turns into a contract check. Use either `ann` or `inst` instead. In this case you can use `inst` as in `((inst set Nothing))` so that the result of the union is `(Setof Symbol)`